# transform matrix numbers with color codes

Tags: r, matrix, plot, colors

I have a matrix that looks like this

```
set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(runif(20,-6,6),5)

> X
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]        [,4]
[1,] -2.8138960  4.780676 -3.528305 -0.02760909
[2,] -1.5345132  5.336103 -3.881319  2.61142210
[3,]  0.8742404  1.929574  2.244274  5.90287314
[4,]  4.8984935  1.549369 -1.390755 -1.43957785
[5,] -3.5798168 -5.258565  3.238097  3.32934266
```

and I want to use the numbers in it to define the colors for a graph, like this.

```
X[X >= 6] <- "#4575B4"
X[X <  6] <- "#74ADD1"
X[X <  4] <- "#ABD9E9"
X[X <  2] <- "#E0F3F8"
X[X <  0] <- "#FEE090"
X[X < -2] <- "#FDAE61"
X[X < -4] <- "#F46D43"
X[X < -6] <- "#D73027"
```

However, I get the following matrix

```
> X
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
[1,] "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090"
[2,] "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090"
[3,] "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090"
[4,] "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090"
[5,] "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090" "#FEE090"
```

What can I do to use the colors I want? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `cut`

```
lab <- c("#D73027", "#F46D43", "#FDAE61", "#FEE090", "#E0F3F8", 
              "#ABD9E9",  "#74ADD1", "#4575B4")
 X1 <- X
 X1[] <- as.character(cut(X, breaks=c(-Inf,
                     seq(-6, 6, by=2), Inf), labels=lab))

 X1
 #      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
 #[1,] "#FDAE61" "#74ADD1" "#FDAE61" "#FEE090"
 #[2,] "#FEE090" "#74ADD1" "#FDAE61" "#ABD9E9"
 #[3,] "#E0F3F8" "#E0F3F8" "#ABD9E9" "#74ADD1"
 #[4,] "#74ADD1" "#E0F3F8" "#FEE090" "#FEE090"
 #[5,] "#FDAE61" "#F46D43" "#ABD9E9" "#ABD9E9"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
XX <- X

XX[X >= 6] <- "#4575B4"
XX[X <  6] <- "#74ADD1"
XX[X <  4] <- "#ABD9E9"
XX[X <  2] <- "#E0F3F8"
XX[X <  0] <- "#FEE090"
XX[X < -2] <- "#FDAE61"
XX[X < -4] <- "#F46D43"
XX[X < -6] <- "#D73027"
XX
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
[1,] "#FDAE61" "#74ADD1" "#FDAE61" "#FEE090"
[2,] "#FEE090" "#74ADD1" "#FDAE61" "#ABD9E9"
[3,] "#E0F3F8" "#E0F3F8" "#ABD9E9" "#74ADD1"
[4,] "#74ADD1" "#E0F3F8" "#FEE090" "#FEE090"
[5,] "#FDAE61" "#F46D43" "#ABD9E9" "#ABD9E9"
```